# How do I make this into a working CRS in ArcGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, coordinate-system

+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-114 +k=0.9999 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs

I have this text string which I successfully used to project data in QGIS. How do I use this to define a CRS in ArcGIS and project my data correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you have Qgis, you can ask gdalsrsinfo in the OSGeo4w shell:

```
gdalsrsinfo "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-114 +k=0.9999 +x_0=0 +y
_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"

PROJ.4 : '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-114 +k=0.9999 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80
+towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs '

OGC WKT :
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["GRS 1980(IUGG, 1980)",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["GRS80",6378137,298.257222101],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-114],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9999],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

The WKT parameters should be usable with Arcgis.